# In Microsoft Dynamics, 365, why can't I inline an instance of FormDataSource?

Tags: compiler-errors, refactoring, local-variables, dynamics-365-operations, unused-variables

I have the following method which compiles:

```
    private void onModifiedFilter(FormControl sender)
    {
        FormDataSource mainAccount_ds = sender.formRun()
            .dataSource(formDataSourceStr(MainAccount, MainAccount));
        mainAccount_ds.executeQuery();
    }
```

As I have no other use for `mainAccount_ds`, I would like to inline the value and simplify the code to:

```
    private void onModifiedFilter(FormControl sender)
    {
        sender.formRun()
            .dataSource(formDataSourceStr(MainAccount, MainAccount))
            .executeQuery();
    }
```

However, this fails to compile with:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       ClassDoesNotContainMethod: Class 'FormObjectSet' does not contain a definition for method 'executeQuery' and no extension method 'executeQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'FormObjectSet' is found on any extension class. Packt_MainAccountExtension (ISV) [ExpenseManagement]    C:\AOSService\PackagesLocalDirectory\Bin\XppSource\ExpenseManagement\AxClass_Packt_MainAccountForm_Extension.xpp    18

- How/why does capturing `mainAccount_ds` alter the ability for this method to compile?
- Are there other ways I can express this without the unnecessary data capture?
- When else in D365 should I expect some magic where I will need to capture a value in order to make use of it, rather than directly invoking a method upon an uncaptured return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your main question: Because the compiler cannot determine the correct downcast type from the return value of the `dataSource` method.

To answer your additional questions:

- "How/why does capturing mainAccount_ds alter the ability for this method to compile?"

The addition of the `mainAccount_ds` variable tells the compiler what type of the return value of the `dataSource` method is expected at run time. Note that the `executeQuery` method is only defined in the `FormDataSource` class, but not in the `FormObjectSet` parent class, which is the type of the return value of the `dataSource` method.

- "Are there other ways I can express this without the unnecessary data capture?"

I don't think so. While there is an `as` operator to do explicit downcasts, I haven't found a way to use it inside a chained method call expression.

- "When else in D365 should I expect some magic where I will need to capture a value in order to make use of it, rather than directly invoking a method upon an uncaptured return value?"

I hope the other answers cleared up that no magic is happening here. The compiler correctly prevents you in this case from an undefined downcast.

In addition, you might want to read up on casting in [x++](/questions/tagged/x%2b%2b). [Casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/new-x-debugger-features#casting) and [Expression operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-operators#expression-operators) are a good place to start.

Comment: Cheers for the response.  If I understand correctly, in X++, when I capture a value the system will implicitly downcast without my needing to tell the system to do something like `FormDataSource mainAccount_ds = (FormDataSource ) sender.formRun()
            .dataSource(formDataSourceStr(MainAccount, MainAccount));` as I might expect in some other language? (And I guess is not even a possibility to  do it like `((FormDataSource ) sender.formRun()
            .dataSource(formDataSourceStr(MainAccount, MainAccount)))
            .executeQuery();`

Comment: That's a "Yes" to both assumptions/questions. Again, I recommend reading [Casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/new-x-debugger-features#casting), it should make things much clearer.